# GridBagLayout Not Keeping Order

Tags: java, swing, layout, layout-manager, gridbaglayout

I am trying to make a simple two column view in a particular order.

It should look like this :

Two Static headers in the top row, and 5 panels per column underneath each

The result I am getting however is a blank table on the left and all the details lined up horizontally on the right. The problem is the details are loaded live from the internet and refresh every 8 seconds, so I would need to update each individual cell as the data refreshes (Which is why I'm not using `GridLayout`)

The code loops infinitely (constantly bringing up up-to-date data till exit)
I can't initialize all the `JPanels` beforehand as it takes a minimum of 6 seconds to get each data point from online.

Could you help me sort out the order? Thanks

```
    import NeuralNet.NeuralNet;

    import javax.swing.*;
    import java.awt.*;

public class MWindow {

public MWindow(String[] c){

    JFrame mainFr = new JFrame("Current Predictions");
    mainFr.setSize(800, 800);
    mainFr.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    mainFr.setVisible(true);
    JPanel p = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
    GridBagConstraints cns = new GridBagConstraints();
    cns.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    cns.insets = new Insets(5,5,15,15);
    mainFr.add(p);


    JTextArea man = new JTextArea("MANUFACTURING 5");
    cns.gridx = 0;
    cns.gridy = 0;
    cns.weightx = 1.0;
    cns.weighty = 1.0;
    cns.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    p.add(man, cns);
    JTextArea inter = new JTextArea("INTERNET 5");
    cns.gridx = 1;
    cns.gridy = 0;
    cns.weightx = 1.0;
    cns.weighty = 1.0;
    cns.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    p.add(inter, cns);

    JPanel aapl = new JPanel();
    JPanel msft = new JPanel();
    JPanel intc = new JPanel();
    JPanel ibm = new JPanel();
    JPanel tsla = new JPanel();
    JPanel fb = new JPanel();
    JPanel goog = new JPanel();
    JPanel yhoo = new JPanel();
    JPanel twtr = new JPanel();
    JPanel amzn = new JPanel();

    p.setBackground(Color.white);
    mainFr.setBackground(Color.white);

    while (true) {
        for (String cmp : c) {
            JPanel stkPanel = new JPanel();
            stkPanel.setBackground(Color.white);
            if (!(cmp.equals("INTER5") || cmp.equals("MANU5") || cmp.equals("ALL"))) {

                Asset a = new Asset(cmp);
                NeuralNet n = Functions.loadNN(cmp);
                NeuralNet nA = Functions.loadNN("ALL");
                NeuralNet n5;
                if (cmp.equals("MSFT") || cmp.equals("AAPL") || cmp.equals("INTC") || cmp.equals("IBM") || cmp.equals("TSLA")) {
                    n5 = Functions.loadNN("MANU5");
                } else if (cmp.equals("TWTR") || cmp.equals("YHOO") || cmp.equals("GOOG") || cmp.equals("FB") || cmp.equals("AMZN")) {
                    n5 = Functions.loadNN("INTER5");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("ERROR");
                    n5 = n;
                }

                double pred = n.PredictRows(Functions.formatData(a));
                double pred5 = n5.PredictRows(Functions.formatData(a));
                double predA = nA.PredictRows(Functions.formatData(a));
                JTextArea stkPred = new JTextArea();
                stkPred.setText("Stock: " + cmp +
                        "\nCurrent Price: " + "$" + a.getCurrPrice().toString() +
                        "\nPrediction 1: " + Double.toString(pred) +
                        "\nPrediction 2: " + Double.toString(pred5) +
                        "\nPrediction 3: " + Double.toString(predA));
                stkPred.setFont(new Font("Helvetica", Font.BOLD, 15));
                int pr = Functions.calcBS(pred, pred5, predA);
                JTextArea act = new JTextArea();
                if (pr == -1) {
                    act.setText("SELL");
                    act.setForeground(Color.red);
                } else if (pr == 1) {
                    act.setText("BUY");
                    act.setForeground(Color.green);
                } else {
                    act.setText("HOLD");
                    act.setForeground(Color.orange);

                }
                act.setFont(new Font("Helvetica", Font.BOLD, 15));

                stkPanel.add(stkPred);
                stkPanel.add(act);

                switch (cmp) {
                    case "MSFT":
                        msft.removeAll();
                        msft.add(stkPanel);
                        msft.revalidate();
                        msft.repaint();
                        cns.gridx = 0;
                        cns.gridy = 2;
                        cns.weightx = 1.0;
                        cns.weighty = 1.0;
                        cns.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
                        p.add(msft, cns);
                    case "AAPL":
                        aapl.removeAll();
                        aapl.add(stkPanel);
                        aapl.revalidate();
                        aapl.repaint();
                        cns.gridx = 0;
                        cns.gridy = 1;
                        cns.weightx = 1.0;
                        cns.weighty = 1.0;
                        cns.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
                        p.add(aapl, cns);
                    case "INTC":
                        intc.removeAll();
                        intc.add(stkPanel);
                        intc.revalidate();
                        intc.repaint();
                        cns.gridx = 0;
                        cns.gridy = 3;
                        p.add(intc, cns);
                    case "IBM":
                        ibm.removeAll();
                        ibm.add(stkPanel);
                        ibm.revalidate();
                        ibm.repaint();
                        cns.gridx = 0;
                        cns.gridy = 4;
                        p.add(ibm, cns);
                    case "TSLA":
                        tsla.removeAll();
                        tsla.add(stkPanel);
                        tsla.revalidate();
                        tsla.repaint();
                        cns.gridx = 0;
                        cns.gridy = 5;
                        p.add(tsla, cns);
                    case "TWTR":
                        twtr.removeAll();
                        twtr.add(stkPanel);
                        twtr.revalidate();
                        twtr.repaint();
                        cns.gridx = 1;
                        cns.gridy = 4;
                        p.add(twtr, cns);
                    case "FB":
                        fb.removeAll();
                        fb.add(stkPanel);
                        fb.revalidate();
                        fb.repaint();
                        cns.gridx = 1;
                        cns.gridy = 1;
                        p.add(fb, cns);
                    case "AMZN":
                        amzn.removeAll();
                        amzn.add(stkPanel);
                        amzn.revalidate();
                        amzn.repaint();
                        cns.gridx = 1;
                        cns.gridy = 5;
                        p.add(amzn, cns);
                    case "GOOG":
                        goog.removeAll();
                        goog.add(stkPanel);
                        goog.revalidate();
                        goog.repaint();
                        cns.gridx = 1;
                        cns.gridy = 2;
                        p.add(goog, cns);
                    case "YHOO":
                        yhoo.removeAll();
                        yhoo.add(stkPanel);
                        yhoo.revalidate();
                        yhoo.repaint();
                        cns.gridx = 1;
                        cns.gridy = 3;
                        p.add(yhoo, cns);
                }
                p.add(stkPanel);
                p.revalidate();
            }
        }

        try {
            Thread.sleep(10000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, I strongly suggest you have a look at [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/), as you are violating the single threaded nature of Swing.

I'd suggest you then have a look at [Worker Threads and SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html) for a possible solution.

You have a lot going on in your code, lots of things getting added and removed and created, which is just plain confusing.

The information you're generally updating isn't that dynamic, the data is, but the way it's presented isn't.

So, what I would suggest doing instead is, create a single custom class which encapsulates the information you want to display, this becomes the model, then create a single custom class which can display the information in the format you want.

I would then create a number of these components and place them within the container in whatever fashion you want, maybe using a `Map` to bind them (so you can look up the component for a given data source when it changes).

Then, I would simply pass the data/model to the appropriate component when it changes and it could simply update the display.

Based on what I can tell from your code, a `JTable` would probably go along way, as well as series of `JLabel`s/`JTextField`s, making it much easier to update the UI from.

It would also make it easier to add/remove data sources